# Which network interface cards support hardware timestamps (hardstamps)

Tags: network-adapter

We are looking for network cards that support hardware timestamps (hardstamps). We need this for capturing packets with high precision and also do synchronisation using PTP / IEEE 1588.

On the web, there are plenty of resources where people say that they are using Intel cards or others, but none of them lists actual product names.

Where can I find detailed information on this or can you recommend any network card that can do these things? How can I ensure that the card also takes hardstamps for non-PTP packets?

### Update

In the meantime I got an answer from Intel confirming that the adapters I340 and I350 support hardstamps for PTP. Unfortunately, the data sheets do not state whether there is also support for hardstamping non-PTP packets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the meantime, someone answered me at [Network Engineering SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23402/how-do-hardware-timestamps-hardstamps-work)

It seems like the Intel 82580 network controller supports this. It is e.g. contained in the Intel I340 server adapter family.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience these NIC's support HW timestamping (yes... all Intel):

Intel X722
Intel I350
Intel I210
Intel I217-V
Intel I217-LM
Intel I218-V
Intel I218-LM
Intel I219-V
Intel I219-LM
Intel 82574L

Note: I suspect the series of I217/I218/I219 suffers from PTP issues under traffic.