# Looking for external NIC (usb to ethernet adapter) that support HW timestamping for PTP

Tags: ethernet, network-adapter

I'm well familiar with NICs that supports HW timestamps for PTP. But I want to work with an external NIC that I can just plug in to my laptop with USB connection (and works with Linux).
I was looking around the net and didn't find anything...
The most similar question I found was [this](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/666/which-network-interface-cards-support-hardware-timestamps-hardstamps), but it's still doesn't help me.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks,
Joseph

Comment: Don't suppose you ever came across a product that fits that bill?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You are more than welcome to share if you find anything...